# Unable to display result of spotify api query in a FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a very simple react-native app where I type the name of an artist in a search bar and display a Flatlist of artists that I got using the spotify api.

I have 2 files my App.js that does the rendering and fetcher.js that implements the api calls.

But I'm unable to get the list to appear, I'm unable to set the state of artists.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StatusBar,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import colors from './utils/colors';
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { searchArtist } from './utils/fetcher';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';


export default class spotilist extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      query: '',
      artists: [],
      error: null,
      refreshing: false,
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <TextInput style={ styles.searchBox }
          value={this.state.value}
          onChangeText={ this.makeQuery }
        />
        <Text> {this.state.artists}  </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  makeQuery = debounce(query => {
    searchArtist(query)
      .then((artists) => {
        this.setState({
          artists: this.state.artists,
        });
        //console.log(artists)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }, 400);

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 64,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
  },
  searchBox: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: colors.black,
    borderWidth: 2,
    margin: 16,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    fontWeight: '800',
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 30,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**fetch.js**

```
export function searchArtist(query) {

  const ClientOAuth2 = require('client-oauth2')

  console.log("Query : " + query)

  const spotifyAuth = new ClientOAuth2({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    accessTokenUri: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    authorizationUri: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
    scopes: []
  })

  spotifyAuth.credentials.getToken()
    .then((user) => user.accessToken)
    .then((token) => getQuery(token, query))
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result) // No list :(
      return result
    });
}

function getQuery(token, query) {

  console.log("Query2 : " + query)

  const settings = {
    "url": `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${ query }&type=artist`,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "authorization": "Bearer " + token,
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
    }
  }

  fetch(settings)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const artists = data.artists ? data.artists.items : [];
      console.log(artists)  // I get the list in the debbuger
      return artists;
    });
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return you `fetch` promise in `getQuery`

```
function getQuery(token, query) {

  console.log("Query2 : " + query)

  const settings = {
    "url": `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${ query }&type=artist`,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "authorization": "Bearer " + token,
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
    }
  }

  return fetch(settings)
    .then((res) => res.json());
}
```

And then when you call

```
spotifyAuth.credentials.getToken()
    .then((user) => user.accessToken)
    .then((token) => getQuery(token, query))
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result) // No list :(
      return result
    });
```

`getQuery` will return this promise and you can handle it like you did before in `getQuery`:

```
return spotifyAuth.credentials.getToken()
    .then((user) => user.accessToken)
    .then((token) => getQuery(token, query))
    .then(data => {
      return data.artists ? data.artists.items : [];
    });
```

then you can simple return this promise and handle wherever you want

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now i'm able to get the list of artists in my "makeQuery" routine, but this.state.artists doesn't seem to be set. I tried different implementation of FlatList but impossible to display anything. Can you help me @andrii ?

Comment: Seems you are not update your state with data you got from `makeQuery`
`.then((artists) => {
        this.setState({
          artists: this.state.artists,
        });
        //console.log(artists)
      })`
Try this:
`this.setState({ artists });`

Answer (score 1):

You need to map through the array of artists. All react and react-native components cannot render data outside of data primitives (such as strings and numbers).

Such as:

```
{
  this.state.artists.map(artist => {
    return (
      <Text key={artist.id}>{artist.name}</Text>
    )
  })
}
```

If the elements inside the state.artists array are just strings, just return the artist inside the text element.

The key value is for React to quickly assimilate the virtual dom to dom amidst state changes.